# TDS Unexpectedly Stopped after Imperial Propaganda Challenge Began (march 2014)

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've been playing TDS without issue since around Christmas time.  There was just a recent update a day or two ago (today is march 21st) and I didn't notice anything funny until I opened up TDS this morning.  I was greeted with the Imperial Propaganda Emperor banner that was announcing the new challenge (decorator droid challenge).

I was eager to begin playing.  I sent my first decorator droid to decorate a level.  After that I clicked on the Imperial Officer icon in the top right corner.  The game popped up a message that read "Tiny Death Star has unexpectedly stopped" and it asked me to report or hit ok.  I hit ok the first time and opened it back up and tried again.  Same effect.  So I just kept playing as normally hoping that it would fix itself with a patch or something later on.

As seems to be the case, I couldn't leave well enough alone so I began searching here to see if others have had this issue.  Then I got the bright idea to just restart my phone.  Since the reboot, every time I try to open TDS, I get the unexpectedly stopped message during the Lucas Arts screen and it won't even open up.

This is extremely frustrating.  And I don't dear uninstall and reinstall the app for fear of losing all of my hard-earned data (levels, bux, coins, etc).

I'm not linked on a FB account.  I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S4, running Android 4.4.2.  Tried clearing my Cache.  No change.

**UPDATE: 4:35 PM CST 3/21/14** 
I figured I would try to rule out any other things, hardware related.  So I moved the data from my SD Card to the Phone internal memory.  After doing that, I was able to open and play the program.  But it still stops unexpectedly when I click on the Imperial Officer, or the Album (in the menu) or the Levels (in the store).

I'm curious to know if I can reinstall just the last update as everything seemed to play well up to that point.  If I could reinstall, maybe it would fix the issue.  Any input on where I can find the file for that update?

Comment: Same thing happened to me and since I couldn't get it open I deleted and re installed it started me all over. Don't do that.

Comment: Definitely - that's what I want to avoid, losing all my saved game progress.

Comment: It was a sad day, I might just give up on it. I emailed support but I am sure they won't respond.

Comment: **UPDATE: 4:35 PM CST 3/21/14**
I figured I would try to rule out any other things, hardware related.  So I moved the data from my SD Card to the Phone internal memory.  After doing that, I was able to open and play the program.  But it still stops unexpectedly when I click on the Imperial Officer, or the Album (in the menu) or the Levels (in the store).  

I'm curious to know if I can reinstall just the last update as everything seemed to play well up to that point.  If I could reinstall, maybe it would fix the issue.  Any input on where I can find the file for that update?

Comment: Support will eventually respond, it just might take two or three weeks.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: 12:31 AM CST 3/22/14**
Good news.  I ended up playing for several hours tonight.  At one point I figured I would restart my phone again and just see if TDS would do any updates or anything.  When my phone restarted, my heart sunk as the TDS shortcut icon had disappeared from my main page.

I went into the Google Play Store and searched for it.  It appeared just like I had never used the app before.  So I downloaded and installed it again.  I crossed my fingers in hopes that it didn't wipe out all that I had worked for...and was rewarded with a fully functioning TDS with all my data once I was able to start the app for the first time after the reinstallation.

I'm not 100% sure what happened, but I'm extremely pleased with how it turned out.  In this instance, it was a matter of being patient I guess.  So while I might not have an exact answer, the issue has been resolved.